# strip - file format not recognized with Qt creator on Release but not Debug

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Using qmake on Qt creator

I want to add some parameters and data files to the build directory, so I added this to my `pro` file

```
wordlists.path = $$OUT_PWD/WordLists
wordlists.files += $$PWD/WordLists/*

INSTALLS += \
    wordlists
```

and added a `make install` step at the end of the build steps.

On debug, this works perfectly and the `WordLists` folder, which is in the source folder, is copied to the build folder.

On release, it also works. But when compiling, I get 4 warning `Makefile:2124:install_wordlists] Error 1 (ignored)`, on for each files in the folder to be copied.

The output of the compiler shows

```
strip: /path/to/my/release/folder/WordLists/List1.xml: file format not recognized
make: [Makefile:2124: install_wordlists] Error 1 (ignored)
strip: /path/to/my/release/folder/WordLists/List2.xml: file format not recognized
make: [Makefile:2126: install_wordlists] Error 1 (ignored)
strip: /path/to/my/release/folder/WordLists/List3.xml: file format not recognized
make: [Makefile:2128: install_wordlists] Error 1 (ignored)
strip: /path/to/my/release/folder/WordLists/Parametres.xml: file format not recognized
make: [Makefile:2130: install_wordlists] Error 1 (ignored)
```

While these message apparently don't disturb the good behavior of the make, I am still puzzled by their meaning and why it only appends on release. They could also mean that I do thing fundamentally wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found rather quickly...

Due to an error of mine, the files in `WordLists` where executable. I removed the `+x` flag and the warning is gone.

Comment: What should I do if there are *.sh files in the **WordLists** directory and they _must_ have a executable flag +x?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry.